# how can i save the state of my webview when changing orientation using a webviewfragment

Tags: java, android, savestate

I have a small webView in one of my layouts that act as a news feed from my website.Every time I changed rotation it would reload the web page.

so I edited the code to include a on config change and on restore state.Then adjusted my android manifest to include the config changes which from the dev site says to include orientation and screen size.

This solves the problem of saving the state but in turn creates a new problem which is I have different size layouts for when its in landscape mode on certain devices. but with the manifest set how it is it overrides screen size. is there away to save the state but with out using screen size in my manifest. so then i could use my landscape layout

here is my code for the orientation changes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homescreen);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.neweview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    svHomeScreen = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svHomeScreen);
    svHomeScreen.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.neweview
    );
    wv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    wv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.NORMAL);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
        wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
        wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    wv.canGoBackOrForward(5);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


    wv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    wv.loadUrl(NEWS);
```

then my manifest file has

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Homescreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_homescreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        />
```

ive added a container an a web view fragment but now the view disappears when rotation is landscape. then disappears completly when i switch back. so i tried adding the save out state and savestate to it which loaded the webview when rotated to landscape but crashed the app when going back to portrait

Comment: Have you tried to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your `<activity>` tag (manifest) ?

Comment: yeah tried that and it saves the state but it overrides my screensizes and this is my problem if i delete the |screensize option it reverts back to not saving the state

Comment: You could try placing it inside a fragment - fragments do not get recreated as brutally as Activities when the screen is rotated. You may find the webview inside a fragment just survives the rotation intact.

Comment: could some one show me how to write it as a fragment as ive never used one

Comment: thanks @adelphus the fragment is what i needed i will answer the question below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code that places the WebView in the activity layout as a fragment. In portrait mode, the view is centered, in landscape, it is positioned at the bottom. Both orientations use the same single WebView instance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // load the fragment - we only need to do this when the activity is first created
        // - not on a recreation due to screen rotation, etc
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.container, new WebViewFragment());
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

    // this could go in a separate file
    public static class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
        WebView mWebView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle bundle) {
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.webviewfrag, null, false);
            this.mWebView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.NewsFeedWbview);
            this.mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
            return v;
        }

    }
}
```

res/layout/main.xml (default/portrait mode)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- container layout for the webview fragment
    - note the id for this view is the same in both this and the landscape version -->
   <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="240dp"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout-land/main.xml (landscape)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- container layout for the webview fragment
    - note the id for this view is the same in both this and the portrait version -->
   <FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout/webviewfrag.xml

```
<!-- make the WebView fill its container -->
    <WebView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/NewsFeedWbview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      />
```

Comment: thank you @adelphus will try something like this now

Comment: @:adelphus i tried this last night but when i rotate the screen the view disappears completely. is there anything else to try

Comment: ive also tried adding the save out state and savestate to the webviewFragment. which makes the webview appear in both views. but dosent save the state and also crashes the app when returning to portrait

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply solve all you problems by adding **android:configChanges** for your activity in *AndroidManifest.xml* like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.Home">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok guys so ive sussed it using fragments for the Webview. i made two fragments, one called webivew and one called webviewfragmentlandscape.

then in the on create i loaded the both fragments but make the landscape one invisible until the device goes in to land scape using the config changes method i was already using. here is my new code if any body can improve on what ive doen it would be a big help

this is before the oncreate

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    View Sidepane = findViewById(R.id.NewsFeed);
    View Squarepane = findViewById(R.id.NewsFeed2);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if (Sidepane.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Sidepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

        Squarepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (Squarepane.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            Squarepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Sidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
```

this is in the on create

```
 View Sidepane = findViewById(R.id.NewsFeed);
    View Squarepane = findViewById(R.id.NewsFeed2);

    Squarepane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Sidepane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and this is the fragment for portrait

```
 <<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


   <WebView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="240dp"
   android:id="@+id/NewsFeedWbview"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

   </WebView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

finally the fragment for landscape

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/NewsFeedWbview2"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

   </WebView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you've done will work, but it's not ideal because you have 2 fragments loaded for the same thing which should be unnecessary. Normally you create two layouts for the Activity (one normal, one landscape) with all the custom layout sizes for each and then inflate/load a *single* fragment (with your webview) into it during `onCreate()`. When the screen rotates, Android will load the alternate layout for the Activity but will automagically transfer the fragment to its new layout container (the id's in the two layouts must match) without you needing to do anything else.

Comment: If that didn't make sense(!), I'll try and create an example for what I think you need.

Comment: that would be brilliant as im having sizing issues doing it this way it works but like you say i knew there was a better way